# readonly fields rule in infopath 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath

We have a new requirement to disable all fields in InfoPath form based the dropdown control selection.

please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct read-only rule. Meanwhile, you can achieve that by creating a format rule for each control you need to disable it as the following

- Click on your dropdown control.
- from the above ribbon > add rule > is equal to or based on your requirements > and select any option below formatting section.

[image]

- Now set your field that you need to disable.
- in the rule properties check **disable this control**.

[image]

Comment: great explanation , but it's not bulk action , please i need rule to disable all control as bulk

Comment: unfortunately, you can't achieve that as bulk, you just can copy the rules for each control you need to disable. Note: if you are going to copy the rule you should change the field that you need to disable